# Error using spring framework in android

Tags: android

I am using spring framework in android but we getting error on these

import org.springframework.social.connect.ServiceProviderConnection;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookMobileServiceProvider;

So what is the solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the error is, so I'll get it's a class not found error.  The solution is to get the JAR that contains those classes and put it in your CLASSPATH.

This URL might help:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social/commits/master/spring-social-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/connect/support/ConnectionRepository.java

Once you have it, you'll have to know how to add a JAR to your CLASSPATH in your Android project.